# RoR information needed in routes.rb

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord, rails-routing

My question is to learn a little bit more about resources and routing. I followed ruby on rails tutorial book and started to customize my application.   In my application , I wanna have a user sending a Post and others discuss about that topic by sending photos. I created users without any problem. In the home page , I wanna show all the users posts by date. The topics model is

```
class Topic < ActiveRecord::Base

  attr_accessible :content, :title
  belongs_to    :user
  has_many      :posts
  validates :title, presence: true, length: { maximum: 140 }
  validates :content, presence: true
  validates :user_id, presence: true
  default_scope order: 'topics.created_at DESC'
end
```

posts model is :

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :content 
  belongs_to :topic
  belongs_to :user
  validates :user_id, presence: true
  validates :content, presence: true
  default_scope order: 'posts.created_at DESC'
end
```

and migration is :

```
      create_table "topics", :force => true do |t|
        t.string   "title"
        t.text     "content"
        t.datetime "created_at", :null => false
        t.datetime "updated_at", :null => false
        t.integer  "user_id"
      end

  add_index "topics", ["user_id", "created_at"], :name => "index_topics_on_user_id_and_created_at"
```

my topics_controller :

```
class TopicsController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :signed_in_user, only: [:create, :destroy]
  before_filter :correct_user, only: :destroy

    def show
        @topic = Topic.find(params[:id])
        @posts = @topic.posts.paginate :page => params[:page], :per_page => 20
    end
```

this is my routes.rb:

```
MyPedia::Application.routes.draw do
    resources :users
    resources :sessions, only: [:new, :create, :destroy]
    resources :topics, only: [:show, :create, :destroy]
    resources :posts
    root to: 'static_pages#home'

    match '/topicin/:id',   to: 'topics#show'
```

my show.html.erb is

```
<div class ="center">
<h3><%= @topic.title %></h3>  
<% if  @posts %>
  <% for post in @posts do %>  
    <p><strong><%= post.content %>  

<% end %>  
</div> 
<%end %>
```

my rake routes table is like that:

```
     topics POST   /topics(.:format)         topics#create
      topic GET    /topics/:id(.:format)     topics#show
            DELETE /topics/:id(.:format)     topics#destroy
      posts GET    /posts(.:format)          posts#index
            POST   /posts(.:format)          posts#create
   new_post GET    /posts/new(.:format)      posts#new
  edit_post GET    /posts/:id/edit(.:format) posts#edit
       post GET    /posts/:id(.:format)      posts#show
            PUT    /posts/:id(.:format)      posts#update
            DELETE /posts/:id(.:format)      posts#destroy
```

.I can see my topics in the homepage as links list without any problem. When i click them i want them to show me topic and the posts inside it. 
 when i use localhost:3000 this is what i get now.

```
No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"topics", :id=>#<Topic id: nil, title: nil, content: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil, user_id: 1>}
```

when i use localhost:3000/topics/1

```
SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: posts.topic_id: SELECT  "posts".* FROM "posts"  WHERE "posts"."topic_id" = 1 ORDER BY posts.created_at DESC LIMIT 20 OFFSET 0
```

So I read the instructions , but i cannot find a way to use topics directly. Sorry for long question.This will help me to understand many questions about rails.

Edit 1: I added topic_id to posts table ... the static_pages controller is :

```
class StaticPagesController < ApplicationController
  def home
    @topic = current_user.topics.build if signed_in?
        @topics = Topic.paginate :page => params[:page], :per_page => 20
  end
```

and the mistake is here in _topics.html.erb :

```
 <% for topic in @topics do %>  
!!!!!  <li><%=link_to topic.title, topicin_path(@topic) %></li>  

 <%= will_paginate @topics %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need to check your `link_to` in the home page. It seems like this `link_to` cannot find the user's topic.

You need also `topic_id` in `posts` because you have `belongs_to :topic` in your `Post` model.  Take a look at your migration for `posts`, create the proper migration and `rake db:migrate`.

At last, I don't think that a `user` needs to have topics, a post has topics, not a user. You could then invoke `@user.posts.topic` and `topics.first.posts.first.user`.

Good luck.

Comment: I will try to manage the topics&posts relations now. Actually I want a user to create a topic and write a post about it (title and content) , later other users can answer by posts only ( content ).

Answer (score 0):

As it seems you are using nested attributes but you aren't using nested route resources so the paths are generating the value per topic instead of the topics per post.

You can easily do this by using the `resource do` method

```
resource :posts do 
  resource :topics
end
```

or like Wawa Loo said you need to pass in the relation values

also for your error
`SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: posts.topic_id: SELECT  "posts".* FROM "posts"  WHERE "posts"."topic_id" = 1 ORDER BY posts.created_at DESC LIMIT 20 OFFSET 0`

When you create an has_many or any relation you need to assign the relation value in the db so when you are on post ID 1 and you want it to load the replies the query will search for a reply which's post_id equals 1. so make sure you run the migration to add this relation attribute

Greetings,

Comment: I started to recode every migration again.. I will try to make a clean coding with relations.

Comment: I wouldn't suggest rewriting excisting migrations but rather add or remove new attributes such as relation collumns, else you might lose track and get stuck somewhere(from experience) just make new migration to adjust ur DB